# ffmpeg problem with html5 codecs with iphone

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, codec

i'm on macosx and ffmpeg installed with macports

```
ffmpeg version 0.7.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 28 2011 15:26:07 with gcc 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5490)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --disable-indevs --cc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 --arch=i386
  libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
  libavcodec   52.122. 0 / 52.122. 0
  libavformat  52.110. 0 / 52.110. 0
  libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
  libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
  libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
```

i'm trying to embed html5 video with video-js

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" width="450" height="300" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">
     <source src="/images/video/iphone.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
     <source src="/images/video/test.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
     <source src="/images/video/test.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
     <!-- Flash Fallback. Use any flash video player here. Make sure to keep the vjs-flash-fallback class. -->
     <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="450" height="300" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png", {"url": "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
        <!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
        <img src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" width="450" height="300" alt="Poster Image"
                    title="No video playback capabilities." />
     </object>
</video>
```

In chrome, firefox works good but i can't see any video on the iphone.
I have tried to convert mp4 with this command

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -vcodec libx264  -vpre libx264-ipod640 -b 250k -bt 50k -acodec libfaac -ab 56k -ac 2 -s 480x320 iphone.mp4
```

any help?

Comment: I've tried also HandbrakeCLI without success